# How to move Inline Template of Kendo Mvc Tabstrip into partial

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I currently have the following kendo tabstrip with an inline template:

```
            @(Html.Kendo()
                .TabStrip() 
                .BindTo(Model.Sections, (tabStripItem, tab) =>
                {
                    tabStripItem.Text = tab.SectionName;
                    tabStripItem.Template.InlineTemplate = @<text>

                    <div>
                        <p>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => tab.SectionName)
                        </p>

                        <p>Questions</p>

                        <ul>
                            @foreach (var answer in tab.InterviewReportAnswers)
                            {
                                <li>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => answer.Question) : @Html.DisplayFor(m => answer.Answer)
                                </li>
                            }
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                </text>;
           }))
```

The above works fine, however, I envisage that the template will get more complex so is there a way to move the inline template to an external partial file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it is possible to use the built in MVC helper `partial` to achieve this.

```
tabStripItem.Template.InlineTemplate = (@<text>
                                        @Html.Partial("_InterviewSection", tab)
                                        </text>);
```

Comment: Another option is `.LoadContentFrom("ActionThatReturnsPartial", "Controller", new { Id = Model.Id })` - then you can do server side stuff and return the partial.

Comment: Would `LoadContentFrom` be invoked on `tabStripItem` within binding or on the `TabStrip` control?